# Service Fabric + Castle + Autofac DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 leaking

Tags: autofac, castle-dynamicproxy, service-fabric-actor

Context:
Service Fabric cluster with AutoFac 4.9.4 for DI, Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor for telemetry injection.
We noticed DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 modules leaking.

This is the setup for classes and DI:

```
public class ServiceInstanceGenerator
   {
       private readonly LoggingInterceptor _loggingInterceptor;
       private readonly ProxyGenerator _proxyGenerator;

       public ServiceInstanceGenerator(LoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor, ProxyGenerator proxyGenerator)
       {
           _loggingInterceptor = loggingInterceptor;
           _proxyGenerator = proxyGenerator;
       }

       public TInterface GetActor<TInterface>(ActorId id) where TInterface : class, IActor
       {
           var service = ActorProxy.Create<TInterface>(id);
           return _proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTargetInterface(service, _loggingInterceptor);
       }
       public TInterface GetService<TInterface>(Uri uri) where TInterface : class, IService
       {
           var service = ServiceProxy.Create<TInterface>(uri);
           return _proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTargetInterface(service, _loggingInterceptor);
       }
   }
```

```
internal class ContainerModule : Module
    {

        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<ProxyGenerator>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterInstance(new JsonSerializerOptions() { Converters = { new ByteArrayConverter() } });
            builder.RegisterType<LoggingInterceptor>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<ServiceInstanceGenerator>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<AssignmentsActor>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<TelemetryClient>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
            builder.Register((c, p) => c.Resolve<ServiceInstanceGenerator().GetActor<ITransactions>p.TypedAs<ActorId>))).As<ITransactions>();
        }
        
    }
```

```
 public class AssignmentsActor
 {
     private readonly Func<ActorId, ITransactions> _actorFactory;

     public AssignmentsActor(Func<ActorId, ITransactions> actorFactory)
     {
         _actorFactory = actorFactory;
     }

private ITransactions GetActor(ActorId id)
{
    return _actorFactory(id);
}
```

We tought that by registering the dependencies as single istance and the factory we could prevent the DynamicProxyGenLeaking but with this setup we can find this in the dumps:

[image]